# Categorize a bunch of TIFF Images in different Directories with Python

Tags: python

I have a Directory with many TIFF Images. This is from a Journal/Book. This Book has many Chapters/Covers, but this are not separated and are in one big folder. They all have a number that starts with 001 and the continues for like a thousand more.
It starts with a Cover Picture/the Chapters and the images after that cover Picture belongs to that Chapter.

I want to create a Directory where that first Cover Picture/Chapter and than the pictures after that Cover picture has to move in the directory where the Cover Picture is. The Program has to know when to stop putting images in that first Directory, because a new Cover Image/Chapter has been detected.
After another Cover Picture has been detected, the program makes a new Directory, called like the Cover Pictures and starts putting all the following images in the new Directory,
until it will detect a new Cover Picture and Start this process again.
I will manually change the name of the First Image which is the Cover picture, and then change the name of the second Cover picture and so on, so that the Cover Pictures have a different name as the other images.

It is kind of like a book with many pages and all the Chapters are together. I just want to Put a new Chapter in a Directory with the pages that belong to that Chapter till a new Chapter starts.

I hope someone can help me.

I tried do some research but I did not find any code that helped me.
With Python I Tried the library PIL.

I Hope someone has the time to write a Code that will solve my Problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). If you [edit] the question to include what you tried with PIL someone may be able to help. Right now your question is asking for someone else to write code for you, and that isn't what Stack Overflow is.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to skim through the images and identify the frame numbers of each new chapter yourself - almost certainly many times quicker than trying to learn Python.

Comment: A creative Homework assignment. Write a script that generates a lot of `move` commands (for the OS used) then execute that output (bash or bat file) on the command line. Why do you need PIL to move files, you can execute move statements from Python script if needed, also execute create directory statements for each chapter